# EDMX and bridge table using oracle database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I have an oracle database connected to **ASP.net MVC 5 with entity framework 6** application, all things was going well, until i made a change **(add a new column)** in bridge table:

**the table:**
[image: tab_sub]

**my constraint on table :**
[image: Constraint]

**Sample of data:**
[image: sample of data]

Error::

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 4758:Must specify mapping for all key properties (DECC_TAB_SUB.TAB_ID, DECC_TAB_SUB.PARENT_TAB_ID, DECC_TAB_SUB.STEPROLE_ID) of table DECC_TAB_SUB.   DECC.EntityModel
```

and here's the table in diagram
[image]

and here's the association
[image]

, I have made many searches but unfortunately i didn't find anything helps me.

Comment: `TAB_ID` can't be in the primary key. For EF a junction table's PK should always consist of the two FKs only. Why did you add `TAB_ID`?

Comment: this added to ensure than the tab_id with parent_tab_id and steprole_id  to be added one time only.

Comment: You can do that, but then the table should be a visible entity in the EDMX.

Comment: how i can make it visible through wizard in EDMX?

Comment: Try to remove and re-add it.

Comment: I know this will solve the issue, but i can't delete it , because someone on my company was built it and changed all entities names to be more readable (The most awful thing)

Comment: Then remodify the entity name, no problem.

Comment: This is the last solution , i tried it before a couple of months but i will try again hope it works.

Comment: @GertArnold deleting all entities not works, i added the diagram and the association to the question